# Arranging the dots arround the circle using javascript buggy

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to arrange a dots around a circle. but i am getting the buggy result. some point of degrees ( top and bottom ) not properly positioning. what would be the issue?

how to resolve this?

```js
$(function(){
  
  var globe = $('#center');
  var width = globe.width() / 2 ;
  var height = globe.height() / 2;
  var point = $('.point').width();
  var pointer = $('<div />', {class:'test'});

  
  for(var i = 1; i <=  360; i++) {
    
    pointer.clone().css({
      left: width  + (width) * Math.cos(i * Math.PI / 180),
      top: height  + (height + point) * Math.sin(i * Math.PI / 180)
    }).appendTo('#center');
    
  }
     
 
});
```

```css
#center {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border-radius:50%;
    border:1px solid red;
    position:relative;
    left:200px;
    top:100px;
}

.test {
  
  width:0.1em;
  height:0.1em;
  background:gray;
  position:absolute;
  border-radius:50%;
  
}

.point {
  width:0.5em;
  height:0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="center"></div>
<div class="point"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

```
  top: height  + (height + point) * Math.sin(i * Math.PI / 180)
```

With:

```
  top: height  + (height) * Math.sin(i * Math.PI / 180)
```

Comment: Just maintaining consistency and pointing out the bug. The coding style is his choice.